# How to calculate mode in R but removing NA values

Tags: r, na, mode

I am able to calculate the mode using

```
Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x) 
tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux)); ux[tab == max(tab)]
}
```

However, my data frame has more NA values in it than integers so when I run this Mode, I get back NA.

Is there a way of removing NA values in the above function somehow or would I need to remove NA values from the dataframe initially? If so, how? I tried

```
DF.omit.NA<- na.omit(DF) ###and na.exclude
```

and it produced no rows of data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `na.omit` wrapped around the `unique` elements

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- na.omit(unique(x) )
 tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux)); ux[tab == max(tab) ]
}

Mode(v1)
#[1] 1
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 3, NA, 2, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA)
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now!